# Access Data Base connection using app.config through null exception after running the installed application

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to connect database using app.config, the problem is it works fine in framework (visual studio 2012) but when i create the setup, after running it though quick launch it through null exception for the connection string, here is my connection and exception. The db file is placed in D:\Account\Account\bin\x86\Debug. By connection string it works fine but i want to use the app.config

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
        </configSections>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="myconnection" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Account.accdb"
                providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>




     myconnection = New OleDbConnection
            Dim ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myconnection").ConnectionString
            'Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Account.accdb"
            myconnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
            myconnection.Open()

'Here is the null exception
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Account.Common.ConnectDb()
   at Account.FrmLogin.FrmLogin_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18010 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Account
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Manoj/My%20Product%20Name/Account.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18016 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Your installer creates a "Debug" folder?

Comment: @ Crowcoder  C:\Program Files\Manoj\Accounting this is where it installed, while using connection string i did add database in installer and used the same connection string and it worked but not with app.config

Comment: Well, wherever the database is, you can use this to set the `DataDirectory` : `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\whatever\folder\"); `. Or you can let the user choose where to put the database file and control it with a Setting instead of config file.

Comment: I want to put the database in the path where my project is being installed, and for that it getting the null exception. I think it's problem of configuration.manager , for which I still can't find a solution.

Comment: Does the installer put it there?

Comment: The issue is not the location of the database. If it was, you would be getting an exception other than a `NullReferenceException`; probably a `FileNotFoundException` or something else. As it is, your code must be trying to access a member of an object that doesn't exist. The obvious candidate is `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myconnection").ConnectionString`, i.e. `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myconnection")` is `Nothing`. My suggestion is to add the connection string on the Settings page of the project properties and then use `My.Settings` in code.

Comment: Well, my.seetings  works fine, I figured that even with that keeping access db in program files will not give me write permission. So I created a custom |Datadirectory| and now I'll manually put my database in that path. I still kinda not satisfied with that but at the moment it is working.. please share any other methods if u know